# How to fix wine gecko error while installing something from winetricks

Tags: wine, winetricks

How to fix this when trying to install something through winetricks

```
sha1sum mismatch! Rename <~>/.winetrickscache/./wine_gecko-0.1.0.cab and try again.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because that file does not exist in the `.winetricks` folder. 
But why? For me, the reason was that winetricks downloaded file under a different name - `winegecko.php\?v=0.1.0`. Pretty obvious thing, but it took me an hour and several reinstallations of wine and winetricks to figure it out :(.